# Loki proper ult combo

Tags: smite

What is the proper Ult> basic attack/skill combo using Loki attending to the buffs to basics skills provide?

In the case you have all cd ready and not need of inv for disengage:

For example=> 3, ult , basic(ult cancels 3 buff?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using all the abilities at once, I would say 2,3,4,1. or 2,1,3,4.

Option 1: Make a decoy, Buff, Ult, then use Invisibility to escape.

Option 2: Make a decoy, Invisible to get a better angle (from behind does more to do passive), then Buff into Ult.

It's really your choice but I feel like option one gives you a way to escape if it goes bad. 3 shouldn't be cancelled by ult as long as you do the ult and a basic within the time frame.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Brandon's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270849/101016) I would say:

- Use invisibility to get onto the enemy's blind side
- Decoy the enemy (drop it right on the enemy)
- Buff into the ult as soon as you drop the decoy

You can sometimes catch the enemy long enough that the decoy's explosion will also do some damage.  Being near the decoy also increases the chances of an enemy god hitting your decoy rather than you.

Other than that, using BOTH invisibility and decoy to escape can be a good option.

The thing with Loki is that you need to mix it up a little.  If you keep doing the same combos the enemy will quickly learn your pattern (and know what to look out for to counter/escape).